WHERE clause appearing AFTER a GROUP BY clause in Teradata
I've run across a query in Teradata that has me a bit confused. Consider the following query:
SELECT
ID
, MIN(In_Time) as In_Time
, MAX(Out_Time) as Out_Time
FROM table 
GROUP BY 1
WHERE In_Time IS NOT NULL
AND Out_Time IS NOT NULL

The thing that jumps out at me initially is that the WHERE clause is AFTER the GROUP BY clause. I'm aware that you can reference aliased columns in Teradata in the WHERE clause. What confuses me is that this query runs, without a syntax error, and I'm unsure specifically how the WHERE is functioning here.
In the WHERE clause, is it processing for example the aliased column: WHERE MIN(In_Time) IS NOT NULL? Or is it processing the column before the GROUP BY WHERE In_Time IS NOT NULL?
I've been having trouble finding clear information regarding a query like this. It might just be bad practice on the original developer's part, but any insight would be appreciated!

The position of the WHERE clause in this query has no effect on what it's acting on. WHERE clauses act on pre-aggregated results, so that WHERE clause is the same as WHERE table.In_Time IS NOT NULL AND table.Out_Time IS NOT NULL. If it was desired that it act on post-aggregated results, then it should be switched to a HAVING clause. Again, its position doesn't change its behavior.

This makes sense, thank you. For clarification - is there any reason this does not throw a syntax error in Teradata? I would expect one but it seems that Teradata allows this syntax. For my query translation efforts to another system, I'm just wondering if there would ever be a reason to write the WHERE clause after the GROUP BY.

It's just something Teradata allows. Some RDBMSs are very strict about the order and others are a little softer. There's not reason for it besides a nice little extra feature.

This is a good reminder that aliasing columns with actual column names is a bad practice,  I had to read this several times to understand why this wouldn't fail with an error about using aggregates in a where clause.

BTW, if you look in the explain, you'll see something like First we do ... with a condition of NOT (table.in_time is null)....  So you can tell it's applying the where to the actual column, not the aliased column.

Teradata is older than Standard SQL, the initial query language was based on QUEL (TeQuel) which had a relaxed syntax regarding the order of query clauses (as long as you start with SELECT). Of course, Teradata switched to Standard SQL decades ago, but some of the old syntax is still known to the parser :-) Regarding the alias, the rule is simple: The alias list is only checked if the parser didin't find the name in the column list.
